# Do we need to install a Virtual Machine to run a Cardano Node?

Tags: stake-pool

Why do we need Virtual Machine to run a Cardano Node/ Stake Pool?  Is it possible to run a Cardano Node without Virtual Machine?

Comment: Yes. My favorite way is to run it with docker.

Comment: LOXE currently runs KVM for its stake pool.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to, but you can if you want. It is perfectly possible to run a node / stake pool outside of a VM.

Comment: Perfect! thank you!